# Duplicate javascript event listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I've searched existing questions, and haven't found one that I understand to be applicable to my scenario.

I'm coding a jQuery plugin that must handle document-level events. The plugin will be executed on multiple input[type=text] elements in the same form, and it's possible that document-level event listeners are registered in other open source plugins that I'm using. I suspect there will be conflicts.

Following is an example of the kind of listener I need. It collapses a custom coded combo box when a click, focus or blur event is triggered on any element besides its own components. It's currently written in jQuery, but I'm certainly open to rewriting in JavaScript.

```
$(document).on('click focus blur',function(e)
{
    switch (e.target)
    {
        case $(comboBox)[0]:
        case $(settings.dropdownContainer)[0]:
        break;
        default:
            $(settings.dropdownContainer).addClass('hide');
            $(settings.dropdownContainer + ' ul li').remove();
        break;
    }
})
```

JavaScript .addEventListener is advertised as follows on developer.mozilla.org: "It allows adding more than one handler for an event. This is particularly useful for libraries, JavaScript modules, or any other kind of code that needs to work well with other libraries or extensions."  But I'm not sure how to use .addEventListener to solve my problem.

As I look at the code above, it occurs to me that looping through multiple instances of $(comboBox) might be part of the solution. But I don't know how to code it.

So, what is the best way to avoid event listener problems given my requirements?  Or, if my general approach is wrong, is there a better way to get each instance of comboBox to collapse if a click is detected on an element other than a combo box?

Comment: Event handlers (ie the callback function of an eventListener) is usually designed to delegate events to a few key elements or small group. To cover everything but the components you already control could give a class to all of those components and then it could be something like: `if (e.target != e.currentTarget && !e.target.matches('.classOfComponents')) {...` that should cover  the majority of it if not all. Bind it to `Document`.

Comment: just add some [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) ?

Comment: @zer00ne, yes, I think that might be a solution to the problem of conflicting with other document-level event listeners.  I add an ID to the body of every page in my app, so I could attach the listener to all elements contained within the current body ID.  But Mister Jojo's answer sheds a different light on the problem.

Comment: @MisterJojo, your answer shows me what I was hoping to learn--how JavaScript handles multiple listeners attached to the same element for the same event type.  I imagined that the default behavior might have been either to call only one listener and cancel the others, or to execute none of them.  Now I know that each one is called in the order in which they were added.  That they all execute is a good thing for me.  So, although stopImmediatePropagation is the opposite of what I need, your comment is very helpful.

Comment: I tried to get this to work with JavaScript listeners.  I preceded each addEventListener with a removeEventListener, but the listeners increased in number each time the plugin was called, crippling the app.  So I reverted to jQuery.  The plugin is working, but I'm afraid it won't play well with other plugins that listen at the document level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.off()`. Events will fire the normally. *myNamespace* is whatever you want to call it. Namespacing will prevent the duplicate listener.

```
$(document).off('.myNamespace'); //Thanks to venimus 
$(document).on('click.myNamespace focus.myNamespace blur.myNamespace',function(e)
{
    switch (e.target)
    {
        case $(comboBox)[0]:
        case $(settings.dropdownContainer)[0]:
        break;
        default:
            $(settings.dropdownContainer).addClass('hide');
            $(settings.dropdownContainer + ' ul li').remove();
        break;
    }
})
```

You may find the following usefull:

https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

and

https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/

Thanks to [Venimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623288/venimus) for the abreviated .off() code!

Comment: Actually the best part of namespaces is that you could simply write `$(document).off('.myNamespace');`

Comment: That is great to know!  Updating answer.